# Data type mismatch in criteria expression. MS AccessDB (cmd:ExecuteNonQuery())

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Trying to update data in AccessDB using following code.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Saumil\Projects\REV-OEM\LoginInforREVOEM.accdb");
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from ManualRunSettings", conn);

DataSet dss = new DataSet();
da.Fill(dss, "ManualRunSettings");

//Pump1
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE ManualRunSettings SET [Pump1RunAccording] = @Pump1RunAccording WHERE [ID] = '1'", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pump1RunAccording", domainUpDown1.Text);
da.UpdateCommand = cmd;
da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am having following error,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Can anyone lead to where the problem might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you change `'1'` to `1`?

Comment: The database has the ID as a number not a string.  Change '1' which is a string to just 1 which is a number.

Comment: value of domainUpDown1.Text is "Manual" Pump1RunAccording to of Text Type in database

Comment: @mjwills that was it. Thank you,

Comment: @jdweng thank you too :)